# I have an error that appears when I type the command : npm install but node.js version 18.16.1 is already installed. Someone to help me to solve it?

Tags: node.js

Here is the error :
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: OpenSSL configuration error:
8C560000:error:80000005:system library:BIO_new_file:Input/output error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin, rb)

I've tried to read the documentation of node.js but I didn't find something interesting that could be help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall Node.js to uninstall the node and npm successfully, and then please restart your computer. Then please go to https://nodejs.org/en/ to download LTS version and install it.

If you still have the error, please downgrade the node version to 16.13.0.

Answer (score 0):

Reupload Node (download latest version)

Comment: OK, but how? Edit your answer with some script that downloads the latest node version or post a guide on how to do this manually.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).